# PHP Excel file downloaded via browser not opened by MS-Excel/OpenOffice

Tags: php, wordpress, excel-2007, phpexcel

[PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com)'s [simple exmple](http://www.codeplex.com/Download?ProjectName=PHPExcel&DownloadId=94244) is correctly working for me on my local machine setup. It is downloading .xlsx file and MS-Excel program happly opens it.

Now I copied this code to my WordPress plugin to allow Excel download from **WordPress Admin** section

```
if ( file_exists(CHECKIN_PLUGIN_DIR . '/lib/PHPExcel.php') ) {
    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start();

/** Include PHPExcel */
require (CHECKIN_PLUGIN_DIR . "/lib/PHPExcel.php");
require (CHECKIN_PLUGIN_DIR . "/lib/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php");

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
                             ->setTitle("PHPExcel Test Document")
                             ->setSubject("PHPExcel Test Document")
                             ->setDescription("Test document for PHPExcel, generated using PHP classes.")
                             ->setKeywords("office PHPExcel php")
                             ->setCategory("Test result file");


// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!')
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('D2', 'world!');

// Miscellaneous glyphs, UTF-8
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A4', 'Miscellaneous glyphs')
            ->setCellValue('A5', 'éàèùâêîôûëïüÿäöüç');

// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');

// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="myfile.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

// Save Excel 2007 file
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
//$objWriter->save("/home/user/ExcelTests/test01.xlsx");
$objWriter->save('php://output');  

exit;
}
?>
<div class="wrap">
....
```

But the file downloaded can not be opened by the excel, it says `Different format than specified by the file extension....` and when opened shows bunch of hexa chars

```
PKU~AG�D�X�[Content_Types].xml��MN�0��"�%nY ��vAa �(0��ؖg�w{&i�@�nbE�{��y��d۸l m�����X�(���)���F��;@1_�����c)j�x/%��E��y� �QĿi!��K�
```

When I changed the code to save it as a file in hard disk, it can be opened without any issues.

```
if ( file_exists(CHECKIN_PLUGIN_DIR . '/lib/PHPExcel.php') ) {
    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start();

/** Include PHPExcel */
require (CHECKIN_PLUGIN_DIR . "/lib/PHPExcel.php");
require (CHECKIN_PLUGIN_DIR . "/lib/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php");

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
                             ->setTitle("PHPExcel Test Document")
                             ->setSubject("PHPExcel Test Document")
                             ->setDescription("Test document for PHPExcel, generated using PHP classes.")
                             ->setKeywords("office PHPExcel php")
                             ->setCategory("Test result file");

// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!')
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('D2', 'world!');

// Miscellaneous glyphs, UTF-8
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A4', 'Miscellaneous glyphs')
            ->setCellValue('A5', 'éàèùâêîôûëïüÿäöüç');

// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');

// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
/*
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="myfile.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
*/

// Save Excel 2007 file
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save("/home/user/ExcelTests/test01.xlsx");
//$objWriter->save('php://output');

exit;
}
?>
<div class="wrap">
....
```

Same happend for Excel5 format too.

But the CSV downloaded via browser has no issues.

Any help?

**Update**

File downloaded vi browser is [here](http://www.filedropper.com/viabrowser)

File saved to filesyestem is [here](http://www.filedropper.com/viasave)

Found an additional line feed char `0A` before PK in downloaded file when viewed in Hexa editor

I tried to remove that line feed using [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

```
// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
ob_end_clean();
ob_start();

// Save Excel 2007 file
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');

$ob_content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="export.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
echo trim($ob_content);
exit;
```

But even after that `0A` is there at the start of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This almost certainly means that you're outputting something additional to the content of the xls file, such as white spaces or a BOM header. Open the file in a text editor, and look for any whitespace characters such as tabs, spaces, new lines, etc at the very beginning (before the PK characters) or end of the file, or for any obvious PHP error messages in the file itself.

Comment: yeah, the is an additional `0A` line feed before PK in downloaded file when viewed in Hexa editor

Comment: In that case, somewhere in your script, there's a blank line outside of ?> <?php tags, that's being injected into the file because it's treated as output by PHP

Answer (score 1):

I use this code on my project and this works well:

```
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);   

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '.xlsx"');

$objWriter->save('php://output');
```